# Clip Raster by Attribute values

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, vector, clip

I have a raster which I want to do a clip with a vector layer (polygon) using its atttribute values.
What I have done so far is the folliwing:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import processing   
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

VECTOR = QgsVectorLayer('MyShapefile.shp','MyShapefile','ogr') 
RASTER = QgsRasterLayer('MyRaster','MyRaster')
row_info = VECTOR.getFeatures()
for row in row_info:
   row_name = row['NAME_FIELD']
   clip = processing.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", RASTER, VECTOR, '0', False, True, True, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, False, 2, False, "", 'OUTPUT\Clip_{}.format(row_name)')
```

I have to use a 'select features' using NAME_FIELD value but I can't find how to iterate throw values, select each value , clip according to that value and go to the next value to clip again.

I am using Python Editor in QGIS 2.18

Answer (score 3):

I guess, you want to iterate features in `VECTOR` layer and clip `RASTER` layer by each feature's geometry, seperately. To do that, you have to select each feature in the `for` loop. If any feature(s) is selected, Processing tools typically operate only on/by that feature(s).

Try following lines:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import processing   
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

VECTOR = QgsVectorLayer('MyShapefile.shp','MyShapefile','ogr') 
RASTER = QgsRasterLayer('MyRaster','MyRaster')
row_info = VECTOR.getFeatures()
for row in row_info:
   row_name = row['NAME_FIELD']

   VECTOR.setSelectedFeatures([row.id()]) # ADD THIS LINE

   clip = processing.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", RASTER, VECTOR, '0', False, True, True, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, False, 2, False, "", 'OUTPUT\Clip_{}.format(row_name)')
```

Comment: Thank you Kadir, I have added that line of code, it runs (execfile(u'c:/user....)but output is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of selecting the polygon try to filter it. So use `VECTOR.setSubsetString` and don't forget on the end of Loop to clear the filter with `VECTOR.setSubsetString ('')`

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import processing   
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

VECTOR = QgsVectorLayer('MyShapefile.shp','MyShapefile','ogr') 
RASTER = QgsRasterLayer('MyRaster','MyRaster')
row_info = VECTOR.getFeatures()
for row in row_info:
row_name = row['NAME_FIELD']
    output_file = "d:\\path_to_save\\" + "cliped_" + str(row['NAME_FIELD']) + ".tif"

    VECTOR.setSubsetString("NAME_FIELD=" + str(row['NAME_FIELD']))

    clip = processing.runalg("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer", RASTER, VECTOR, '0', False, True, True, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, False, 2, False, "", output_file)

    VECTOR.setSubsetString('')
```